# express typescript err throw 'any' warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this small piece of code

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('The sedulous hyena ate the antelope!');
});

app.listen(port, err => { //show error here
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

I wonder why this message pop up

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2769)
```

I didn't declare type for req and res, but why typescript show error only for the err?

Comment: Looks like `listen` in the type definitions never takes an error parameter https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L1031-L1036

Comment: Looking at the node source code - it looks like indeed the callback is never called with an error and it's just `this.once('listening', cb);` - so the type definitions are actually correct here.

Comment: An error would be sent via an `error` event on the server object returned from `app.listen()`.  You can add a separate listener for the error event.

Answer (score 3):

There is no error paramter.

Hold CTRL and then click on `listen`

It will open `index.d.ts` and you will see the definition

```
  listen(port: number, hostname: string, backlog: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
  listen(port: number, hostname: string, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
  listen(port: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
  listen(callback?: () => void): http.Server;
  listen(path: string, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
  listen(handle: any, listeningListener?: () => void): http.Server;
```

As you can see the `callback` takes no argument